# Enclose the value of input button with p

Tags: php, forms, input, woocommerce

How can i enclose the value of my button to p? i trid to add a `<p>` tag but it doesn't work it displayed as a text.

I want to enclose the value so i can add a psuedo element on the button value. or if its possible to select the value via css directly if adding a html on value is not possible can be another solution for this.

This one:

```
<input type="submit" class="button refreshbtn" name="update_cart" value="<?php _e( '<p>Update Cart</p>', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
```

Original Code:

```
<input type="submit" class="button refreshbtn" name="update_cart" value="<?php _e( 'Update Cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
```

Comment: value attribute does not allow html, you can use anchor tag instead.

Comment: I really don't know PHP but will it affect the system? or if i can just select the value on my css that can be another solution...

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not allowed in attributes value, e.g. `value="Submit"` is valid example.
If you want to use HTML for formatting button, you can use `anchor` tag and use JavaScript to submit form (or any other action) on click of that `anchor`.

```
<a id="btnSubmitForm" class="button refreshbtn"><span>Update Cart</span></a>
```